# Find and replace identifier with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm parsing a file containing statements line by line. I want to:

1. Identify all lines containing assignments.
2. Replace identifiers of certain types (Input and Output).

A line is an assignment if it has one of the following two forms:

```
DataType Identifier = ...
Identifier = ...
```

The data type must be one of: "R", "L", "H", "X", "I". The data type is optional. Spaces are allowed in any position around the DataType and the Identifier. Example of lines containing statements:

```
L Input = ...
DigitalOutput = ...
  R Output= ...
H AnalogInput=...
  X Output   = ...
```

Expected result after parsing the statements above would be:

```
L Deprecated = ...
DigitalOutput = ...
  R Deprecated= ...
H AnalogInput=...
  X Deprecated   = ...
```

The file also contains other statements than assignments so its important to identify lines with assignments and only replace identifiers in that case. I've tried to use a regular expression with positive lookbehind and positive lookahead:

```
public void ReplaceIdentifiers(string line)
{
  List<string> validDataTypes = new List<string>{"R", "L", "H", "X", "I"};
  List<string> identifiersToReplace = new List<string>{"Input", "Output"};
  string = ...
  Regex regEx = new Regex(MyRegEx);
  regEx.Replace(line, "Deprecated");
}
```

Where MyRegex is on the form (pseudo code):

```
$@"(?<=...){Any of the two identifiers to replace}(?=...)"
```

The lookbehind:

```
Start of string OR 
Zero or more spaces, Any of the valid data types, Zero or more spaces OR
Zero or more spaces
```

The lookahead:

```
Zero or more spaces, =
```

I haven't managed to get the regular expression right. How do I write the regular expression?

Comment: This is not a question. This is business requirement. You should research, try to do something then if you have any particular code problem, you can ask. But where is the code? I don't see any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since .NET regex supports non-fixed length Lookbehind, you may use the following pattern:

```
(?<=^\s*(?:[RLHXI]\s+)?)(?:Input|Output)(?=\s*=)
```

And replace with `Deprecated`.

**[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cs*%28%3f%3a%5bRLHXI%5d%5cs%2b%29%3f%29%28%3f%3aInput%7cOutput%29%28%3f%3d%5cs*%3d%29&i=L+Input+%3d+...%0d%0aDigitalOutput+%3d+...%0d%0a++R+Output%3d+...%0d%0aH+AnalogInput%3d...%0d%0a++X+Output+++%3d+...%0d%0aIOutput+%3d+...%0d%0aOutput+%3d+...&r=Deprecated&o=m)**.

**C# example:**

```
string input = "L Input = ...\n" +
               "DigitalOutput = ...\n" + 
               "  R Output= ...\n" + 
               "H AnalogInput=...\n" + 
               "  X Output   = ...\n" + 
               "IOutput = ...\n" + 
               "Output = ...";

Regex regEx = new Regex(@"(?<=^\s*(?:[RLHXI]\s+)?)(?:Input|Output)(?=\s*=)", 
                        RegexOptions.Multiline);
string output = regEx.Replace(input, "Deprecated");
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

**Output:**

```
L Deprecated = ...
DigitalOutput = ...
  R Deprecated= ...
H AnalogInput=...
  X Deprecated   = ...
IOutput = ...
Deprecated = ...
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/APBH37357)**.

Comment: Thanks! I will will try your solution! I use this site https://regex101.com/ and it doesn't allow quantifiers inside lookbehind, which was one of my problems... Do I need ?: before Input|Output and why?

Comment: @AndyRehn It's called a non-capturing group. You should only use a capturing group (i.e., without `?:`) when you need to get the value of what's inside the group separated from the full match. You may check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/8967612) for more info.

Comment: I just discovered that the expression doesn't match for example:
Output = ...
How do I make [RLHXI] optional?

Comment: I found the answer:
(?<=^\s*[RLHXI]?\s*)(?:Input|Output)(?=\s*=)
When I replaced  \s+ with \s* after the character class the quantifier ? worked...

Comment: @AndyRehn You're right; I didn't take into account the case where the DataType is absent. Your pattern, however, has one downside. It will match things like `IOutput = ...`. Instead of making each of `[RLHXI]` and the whitespace following it optional separately, you should make them both optional _as one unit_ (using a non-capturing group. That would be something like `(?<=^\s*(?:[RLHXI]\s+)?)(?:Input|Output)(?=\s*=)`. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the particular case shown, your regex can be:

```
^(\s*[RLHXI]\s+)(?:Output|Input)(\s*=)
```

replace with `$1Deprecated$2`, with multiline option.

If both the type names and identifiers to replace are not available at compile time, you can use `string.format` with this format:

```
^(\s*(?:{0})\s+)(?:{1})(\s*=)
```

The arguments you pass to it will be the lists of strings, joined with `|`, using `string.Join`:

```
string regex = string.Format(
    @"^(\s*(?:{0})\s+)(?:{1})(\s*=)",
    string.Join("|", validDataTypes), // you should probably escape these beforehand
    string.Join("|", identifiersToReplace)
    );
```